# Hibernate JDBCConnectionException: could not update

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, c3p0

In a Java + Hibernate aplication, we get a JDBCConnectionException:

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not update: [net.gencat.cultura.itinerarisLectura.model.AppVariables#14]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2421)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2303)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2603)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at hibernate.util.ManagedSession.rollbackTransaction(ManagedSession.java:64)
    at net.gencat.cultura.itinerarisLectura.model.home.AppVariablesHome.attachDirty(AppVariablesHome.java:122)
    at net.gencat.cultura.itinerarisLectura.struts.action.AppVariablesAction.save(AppVariablesAction.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1526.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:280)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:216)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at net.gencat.cultura.itinerarisLectura.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:199)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:282)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:767)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:697)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Se ha producido una excepción durante el método DBComms.receive. Operación:Connection reset. Contexto:(173) [Thread[TP-Processor14,5,main], IO:a9a8a, Dbc:53c34]. PktNum:0. TotalReceived:0. PktSize:4.096.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DBComms.receive(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PreparedStatementExecutionRequest.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.CancelableRequest.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcher.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatcher.java:23)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2399)
    ... 41 more
```

What could be? Problem of the Database? Programming bug? Hibernate bad configuration? "Luckily" it only fails in the production database, we can't reproduce at local.

The hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

 <!-- Use the C3P0 connection pool. -->
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">3</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property>
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property>

    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="cache.use_minimal_puts">false</property>
    <property name="max_fetch_depth">3</property>
```

EDIT:

At the same log file I also get the next message, that could be important

```
WARN  [TP-Processor7] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection - [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
WARN  [TP-Processor7] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection - [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: La conexión está cerrada. ] which will not be reported to listeners!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very big on reading Microsoft SQL Server error messages in Spanish, but it looks like connection to the server was lost. Either server was restarted or something happened in the network.

Comment: Thanks! (Sorry, I didn't realize that part of the message was in Spanish)